# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag

Tags: java

I am just trying to use JSTL and inside trying to fetch from my MySQL database table. If I run it normally as a java application it's working and I'm connecting with the database, but in my JSP it's not happening and this error is showing constantly. (Note that I'm not doing Maven project, it's a simple Dynamic web project.)

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/sql/SQLExecutionTag
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3ykX.png)

I'm searching for quite a while now and I think it's happening because of my JSTL JAR file. I really searched for a long time and after a while I found a JAR file of JSTL,
[this jakarta.servlet one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5ZtN.png).
I have also tried few more JAR files as I was searching for quite a while:
[these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmgmd.png).
Someone kindly help.
Also is there any way I can get the latest Spring JAR files, or do I have to use sts-4? As I found that Spring JAR files are hidden from everyone now (behind a login password wall).
Thanks.